# Is a smooth Lie group an analytic Lie group?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Maybe related : [Why are Lie groups automatically analytic manifolds?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1856432/why-are-lie-groups-automatically-analytic-manifolds)

I'm seraching for a precise statement. I propose two theorems.

**Theorem 1**

> Let $G$ be a smooth manifold (the transitions functions are $C^{\infty}$ as maps between open subsets of $R^n$). We suppose that $G$ is a group for which the mulliplication and the inverse are smooth.

> Then the transition functions, the multiplication and the inverse are analytic.

**Theorem 2**

> Let $G$ be a smooth manifold (the transitions functions are $C^{\infty}$ as maps between open subsets of $R^n$). We suppose that $G$ is a group for which the mulliplication and the inverse are smooth.

> Then $G$ accepts an analytic atlas for which the multiplication and the inverse are analytic.
> Moreover every two such atlas are analytically diffeomorphic.

My guesses:

- Theorem 1 is wrong because the atlas may contain smooth charts which are not analytic.
- Theorem 2 is true.

QUESTIONS:

- is theorem 1 wrong ?
- is theorem 2 true ?
- can I have a link (online; I do not have access to books) to a precise statement and a proof ?

My aim is to be sure that I can always suppose every Lie groups to be analytic (transition charts, multiplication, inverse) without loss of generality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following charts: around $e$ it's $X \mapsto \exp X$, from a neighborhood of $0$ in $\frak{g}$ to a neighborhood of $e$ in $G$.  Around a $g\in G$ it's $X \mapsto g \exp X$. This give an analytic atlas in which multiplication and inverse is analytic. An argument for this: say we have the chart aroung a $g= \exp X_0$ close to $e$, $X \mapsto \exp X_0 \exp X$. To see the point $\exp X_0 \exp X$ in the chart around $e$ we need to write the equality
$$\exp X_0 \exp X = \exp X_1$$
Now, $X_1$ can be expressed  in terms of $X_0$ and $X$ using the [B-C-H formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula).

Comment: It means "yes" for the existence part of "theorem 2". Thanks.

Comment: @Laurent Claessens: The conclusion is that a $C^{\infty}$ Lie group "is" an analytic Lie group in a very precise sense -- unique also.  This can be proved similarly for Lie group of class $C^{3}$ (and more difficult but still true for lower class, up to $C^0$).